# Unable to open Jupyter Notebook instance on AWS Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I was working on the Notebook instance yesterday and was able to run some scripts successfully, but this morning I was unable to connect to the notebook instance. I keep on getting the loading icon before 504 error appears. Not sure if this is related to memory since I am currently using t2.medium and I can upgrade if that's the case. My only concern with this is that the data shouldn't be lost.

Any help on how I can check what issue is will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Sagemaker Notebooks!

If you are using lifecycle configuration, I would suggest disassociating it to rule it out as an issue. Here's a doc that explains how to do that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_UpdateNotebookInstance.html

If you are still facing this issue, I would suggest reaching out to AWS support with your notebook instance ARN so this can be debugged further.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I stopped the instance and start again.
It worked in my case.
Below is step by step guide.

1. 'Amazon SageMaker' > 'Notebook instances' menu
2. Click the instance which is not responding
3. upper-right corner, click 'Stop' button
4. Start again